# How to read CSV file group by group

Tags: c#, csv, readfile

I want to read a `.csv` file which has some repeated lines. I want to read between this repeated line. For example a is the repeated line and before the second a, I have lines such as 1,2,3.

I want to read write these values between a values. Can you help me?

Comment: provide your csv file format,add sample input and tell us expected output.how can we help without seeing any code or some text?

Comment: i tried to explain in my question, my first line a ,second line 1 and it will come a again in the line and it will contiune to come like that like a 1 a 2 a 3 i want to read 1 2 and 3

Comment: Here's an example question that shows how to present the input and output, along with some sample code - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21650278/how-to-write-data-in-a-csv-file-from-different-functions-in-r-one-after-another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bit unclear. But perhaps this will do:

```
var lines = new List<string>(File.ReadLines("input.csv"));
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    if (line.StartsWith("a")) continue;
    // insert code to modify the other lines
}
// ... and later
File.WriteAllLines("output.csv", lines);
```